# how to set icon center in fab in android

Tags: java, android, xml, icons, floating-action-button

how to icon center in `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton` in android ?

when I run the app in normal screen size of mobile then properly show, but I run the app in 10' inch tablet then fab size is small, so how to implement fab properly in any size of the screen in android?

Thanks, in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have these choices.

1. Design a separate layout for tablet or large screen devices and set `Fab` to custom size with this attribute.

```
app:fabCustomSize="100dp"
```

2. Make sure you are not overriding the attribute `app:fabSize` with value `mini` or `normal`. By default your fab size  value is fixed to `auto`

```
app:fabSize="auto"
```

3. Based on how it want to look, you can change the fab to extended by using this `<tag`

```
com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
```